# Gym observation_space -- the `reset()` method does not match the given observation space

Tags: python

I am working on creating a custom env.

Checking with: stable_baselines3.common.env_checker

```
from stable_baselines3.common.env_checker import check_env
import pandas as pd
from env import MainEnv

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
env = MainEnv(df=df, group_size=5, index=0)
check_env(env, warn=True, skip_render_check=True)
```

**MainEnv**

def init

```
self.observation_space = Box(low=-np.inf, high=np.inf, shape=(25,), dtype=np.float32, seed=0)
```

return from reset()

```
observation
[-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0]
Shape: (25,)
```

observation_space

```
Box([-inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf
 -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf], [inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf
 inf inf inf inf inf inf inf], (25,), float32)
```

Error:

```
AssertionError: The observation returned by the `reset()` method does not match the given observation space
```

I have a feeling I am missing something basic.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem, probably you are using the wrong datatype in the array you are returning from env.reset(). Make sure to use dtype = np.float32 again:

```
box = spaces.Box(low = 0.,high = 1.,shape =(1,),dtype = np.float32)  
wrong = np.array([0.5])  
print(box.contains(wrong)) # this prints false  
correct = np.array([0.5],dtype = np.float32)  
print(box.contains(correct))#this prints true
```